# Is there a tool to delete unwanted files from node_modules, even from the used packages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, node-modules, serverless, aws-serverless

The use case here is AWS lambda. Nowadays, npm module contains all the documentations, tests, examples, websites, etc. So when we upload the zip, it has all the files that are not needed.

Comment: Are you using the serverless framework or SAM?

Answer (score 0):

There is an npm package that does exactly this. It's called node-prune. It removes pretty much everything that isn't code.

Install instructions:

```
npm install -g node-prune
```

Usage:
Navigate to the root directory of your project in a terminal and type

```
node-prune
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-prune

**NB:** It doesn't look like this is being currently maintained, but there isn't a lot to it to maintain. Still works fine for me and it still downloaded approx. 500 times a week according to npmjs.com.

Answer (score 0):

this is another module that make the same job and worth trying https://github.com/tj/node-prune.

( from readme )

### Installation

From source:

```
$ go get github.com/tj/node-prune/cmd/node-prune
```

From binary to `./bin/node-prune`:

```
$ curl -sfL https://install.goreleaser.com/github.com/tj/node-prune.sh | bash
```

From binary to `/usr/local/bin/node-prune`:

```
$ curl -sfL https://install.goreleaser.com/github.com/tj/node-prune.sh | bash -s -- -b /usr/local/bin
```

### Usage

In your app directory:

```
$ node-prune

files total 27,330
files removed 3,990
size removed 13 MB
   duration 200ms
```

Somewhere else:

```
$ node-prune path/to/node_modules

files total 27,330
files removed 3,990
size removed 13 MB
   duration 200ms
```